# If changing inertial reference changes velocity/energy, shouldn't that produce conflicting observations of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

A particle $X$ has mass $m$ and passes above observer $A$ with an apparent horizontal velocity $v$. Colinear with these is another observer $B$ moving with apparent horizontal velocity $u$. Colinear with all of these is another particle P.

```
X ----------> v
A
B --> u
P
```

In the reference frame of $A$, $X$ has kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and in the reference frame of $B$ X has KE of $\frac{1}{2}m^\prime(v-u)^2$ with relativistically adjusted mass $m^\prime<m$

Doesn't all of this mean that $B$ observes $X$ to have a weaker gravitational field, hence $P$ will accelerate differently according to B *in a direction perpendicular to the movement* and hence noncontracted?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the non-relativistic expression for energy to ask a question where relativity is required.  That's creating your apparent contradiction.  See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation.

Second, your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with gravity specifically.  There is a gravitational force between these particle, but I don't see how you think that matters in the context of your question.